# How to remove duplicate rows from the output of multiple joins of MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I have 3 tables:
Client,
Purchase,
Product

Client Table:

| Cid | ClientName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM |
| 2 | JOE |

Purchase Table:

| PurchaseID | Cid | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

Product Table:

| ProductID | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JAM |
| 2 | BREAD |

After inner joining them it should look like this:
Output:

| Cid | ClientName | ProductID | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | 1 | JAM |
| 1 | SAM | 2 | BREAD |
| 2 | JOE | 1 | JAM |

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT C.Cid, C.ClientName, Pr.ProductID, Pr.ProductName
FROM Client C
JOIN Purchase Pu
ON C.Cid = Pu.Cid
JOIN Product Pr
ON Pu.ProductID = Pr.ProductID
```

Even though I am getting the required results, there are many duplicates in all columns for some rows.
Ex:

| Cid | ClientName | ProductID | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | 1 | JAM |
| 1 | SAM | 1 | JAM |

How to remove one of the duplicate rows from the result?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: DISTINCT is not working. Please note that every row is a unique combination here.

Comment: *there are many duplicates in all columns for some rows* and *every row is a unique combination here* - please select one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add group by to have unique rows.

```
CREATE TABLE client(
cid INT,
client_name varchar(10) );

insert into client values
(1,'SAM'),
(2,'JOE'),
(1,'SAM');

CREATE TABLE purchase (
purchase_id INT,
cid INT,
product_id int );

insert into purchase values
(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(3,2,1);

CREATE TABLE product  (
product_id INT,
product_name varchar(10) );

insert into product values
(1,'JAM'),
(2,'BREAD'),
(1,'JAM');


SELECT C.Cid, C.client_name, Pr.product_id, Pr.product_name
FROM client C
JOIN purchase Pu ON C.cid = Pu.cid
JOIN product Pr ON Pu.product_id = Pr.product_id
group by  C.Cid, C.client_name, Pr.product_id, Pr.product_name;
```

Result:

```
cid client_name product_id  product_name
  2    JOE         1          JAM
  1    SAM         1          JAM
  1    SAM         2          BREAD
```

I added some duplicates values in the Demo to tell the difference.
[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c0cdcd9e06aeaf7e351c760fafecb899)